# How to monitor render process in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: python

I'm currently writing [an addon](https://github.com/adhihargo/layout_tools), the purpose of which requires it to render several parts of active scene sequentially, preferably with UI-responsiveness intact. The problem is the UI freezes if I just directly call `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)`. I get UI-responsiveness by changing the [execution context](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.html#execution-context) to `"INVOKE_DEFAULT"`, but then the code won't wait until a render process finished before executing the next one.

**Using `threading` Module**

Looking for an alternative, I then use Python's [`threading.Thread`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) object to encapsulate render function, like this:

```
def _init_render_thread(self):
    self._render_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=bpy.ops.render.render, kwargs={'animation':True})
```

... and [check](https://github.com/adhihargo/layout_tools/blob/4ea72c1871643404f6ff3bb64f3c0aa2a46e94ee/layout_tools.py#L184) the thread object's [`is_alive`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) method at interval set by a [`Timer`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Timer.html#module-bpy.types) object. Unfortunately it's prone to occasional random crashing, as any thread-related bugs are, so I'm still stuck with this method.

**Chaining Handlers**

Based on [jesterKing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/97/jesterking)'s answer, I then chain the render execution using a scene-global property and render handlers with the following code. By chaining, the operator no longer needs to be modal. It's finishing early, then leaving completion to these handlers:

```
@persistent
def render_pre_handler(dummy):
    props = bpy.context.scene.oha_layout_tools

    if props.render_marker_infos:
        rmi = props.render_marker_infos.pop(0)
        marker_scene_settings(bpy.context, rmi)

@persistent
def render_complete_handler(dummy):
    props = bpy.context.scene.oha_layout_tools

    if props.render_marker_infos:
        rmi = props.render_marker_infos.pop(0)
        marker_scene_settings(bpy.context, rmi)

        bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True)
    else:
        bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.remove(render_pre_handler)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(render_complete_handler)
        props.marker_infos.clear()
        props.render_marker_infos.clear()
```

It still doesn't work. The [`render_complete`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_complete) handler promptly executes even while the render thread itself is still in progress.

Is there any thread-safe way to monitor render process, other than spawning new Blender process?

Comment: You should check http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/445/97 . The modal operator + python timer events is the way to go (as I posted in the comment to this answer)

Comment: Um, I already done that, modal operator and timer object. As stated in my question.

Comment: I see. modal operators are still the way to go. I posted my answer with handler usage.

Comment: Looking at your code, in order for you to use a modal operator the way @jesterKing is suggesting, you would actually have to have two modal operator classes (one for your script as a whole like you have it now, and one just for the render threading)

Comment: Maybe there's some mistake in it, but I did wrote two modal operators [in a previous commit](https://github.com/adhihargo/layout_tools/blob/4c84ad7260b69d3b8cc3cb30894d52d4907937c8/layout_tools.py). The crash occurences were just as frequent and random...

Comment: Maybe use a macro like shown here?

http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3037/1363

Comment: @CoDEmanX: I succeeded using it for several other needs, but still fails for this one. It just won't wait for `INVOKE`d operator to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add handlers for render complete process: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67b_release/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_complete

Use that to flip a flag that you can check in your main code that can check when the current render is ready before starting a new one.

Check also render_post (and render_pre) for usage in your add-on.

Comment: I still fail to use this. I need custom property to sequentialize render processes, but each modification to the property in an operator can't be seen outside that operator (including `render_post` handler), as if it never change. Maybe the monitoring must be done entirely within the modal operator, but I don't know how yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your handlers look fine, but you definitely need to look into other ways to run multiple processes than using the `threading` module. Python's `threading` module is not fully compatible with how Blender operates and is a guaranteed way to generate lots of ugly errors farther down the road.

Other options you should consider:

- **Blender's Modal Operators:** These are *not* the same as the threading module, but are instead essentially Blender's own implementation of threading. Look at the *Operator Modal* template file in Blender's Text Editor for an example of how to use this. *This is the recommended way of multithreading in Blender!*
- **The `multiprocessing` module:** Allows you to utilize multiple GPU/CPU cores for your rendering. This can have the additional advantage of allowing you to greatly speed up your rendering times by rendering multiple images in parallel.
- **The `subprocess` module:** This is by far the simplest way to thread, but only supports command-line operations. If you are willing to do command-line rendering, this should work.
- **The `concurrent.futures` module:** This module is a high-level way of operating parallel threads, that essentially allows you to "queue" jobs to be completed. I haven't used this yet, since it's new in Python 3.x, but I recommend you take a look at it to see if it does what you're looking for.

Comment: I used `subprocess` to spawn Blender processes to render in the background, an old solution to [another addon](https://github.com/adhihargo/render_oha_opengl_animation/commit/46f8923f46f5db39c3d798448f5f8b9a7b09a6e2). IMHO it's horrible from user interaction standpoint, but I think I'll use this if all else fails. The addon must work, elegant or not...

Comment: @Gwenn Isn't threading not recommended for CPU-bound processes because of python's Global Interpreter Lock? and multiprocessing also not recommended because it will create multiple instances of blender?

Answer (score 4):

My current solution to this problem, ugly as it is, is to have a modal operator watch output file's size at interval. Size doesn't change = render is finished, which works here because I'm only rendering audio files, so the process should be fast enough. Here's the relevant chunk of [the code](https://github.com/adhihargo/layout_tools/blob/eed8939e1f13b9b3e69534dae7f3e1c924aa0712/layout_tools.py):

```
def check_render_file(self, context):

    # ... initialization ...

    if not self.prev_stat:
        self.prev_stat = os.stat(context.scene.render.filepath)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    cur_stat = os.stat(context.scene.render.filepath)

    if self.prev_stat.st_size != cur_stat.st_size:
        self.prev_stat = cur_stat

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    # ... cleanup, next render ...

    return {'FINISHED'}

def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'TIMER':
        return self.check_render_file(context)

    return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```