# How to run a python script at regular intervals?

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to run a script every few seconds or so, while letting the interface update in the meantime?

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a script that runs continuously but does not block the interface?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/442/how-can-i-create-a-script-that-runs-continuously-but-does-not-block-the-interfac)

Comment: @RayMairlot Would using a modal operator still let blender behave normally (without things like no shortcuts etc.)?

Comment: Sorry, don't about specifics, just thought the questions looked similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the **Operator Modal Timer** template in the *Text Editor*:

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            return self.cancel(context)

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            # change theme color, silly!
            color = context.user_preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient
            color.s = 1.0
            color.h += 0.01

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

You can specify the interval for the `'TIMER'` event, but note that all active timers will be caught (there is no way to distinguish them).

The [timer class](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Timer.html#module-bpy.types) also comes with some handy attributes:

```
if event.type == 'TIMER':
    print (self._timer.time_duration) # elapsed time since the operator call
    print (self._timer.time_delta)    # elapsed time since the last step
    ...
```

Beware of using threads, [they can crash Blender.](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-using-threading-module)

Comment: Trippy template XD

Answer (score 3):

in blender 2.80 you can do this: (for blender 2.7 I don't know)

```
def timer_call_fnc():
    print('called')
    return 1.0 # call every second

bpy.app.timers .register( timer_call_fnc )
timer_call_fnc() # make first call

# unregister later:
#bpy.app.timers .unregister( timer_call_fnc )
```

more info: [blender 2.80 timer api](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.timers.html)

note: 
"You should never modify Blender DATA at arbitrary points in time in separate threads. "

for addons you might have to make the timer and handler persistent. 
example:

```
# blender 2.8 example 
# persistent timer 
#

from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent   # do not discard, when file changes 
def timer_fired():
   # do stuff
   return 0.5 # seconds 

@persistent
def handler_load_post():
   if not bpy.app.timers  .is_registered( timer_fired ):
       bpy.app.timers .register( timer_fired, first_interval=1.0, persistent=True )

def my_init():
   bpy.app.handlers .load_post .append( handler_load_post )
```