# Controlling drivers with data received via TCP/UDP

Tags: python, properties, shape-keys, network

For a project I need to drive shape keys with data received via a network connection. In my setup I receive input form a TouchOSC app running on an iPad into PureData on a Mac. The input data then is processed and sent out over UDP to 127.0.0.1:13001.

That's all working fine but now I need Blender to receive the packets, evaluate them and use the values to drive properties on objects. In my case I need to drive the value property of shape keys.

Is this possible and if so, how can I approach this the best way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic idea is to open a socket, poll the data and apply the received values to the shape keys:

```
import socket

# open network socket
port = 13001
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", port))
print "waiting on port:", port

# poll data (could use a timer)
data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024) 
print data
# set float value from data
# value convert from data
bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks['Key 1'].value = float(value)
```

Related:

- [Mapping an algorithm to an animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5358/mapping-an-algorithm-to-an-animation)
- http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-in-python/
- [How to run a python script at regular intervals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7885/how-to-run-a-python-script-at-regular-intervals/7887#7887)

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks for your answer. I thought it would be more complex but this works great.

Comment: How would this look on a time operator it crashes blender when I run it