# Can one control a property using real time microphone input

Tags: python, drivers

I believe it to be doable, but what would be the most intelligent way? Does using a scripted driver reading from a sound stream make sense? Is there some easier way to do the trick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling drivers with data received via TCP/UDP](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27959/controlling-drivers-with-data-received-via-tcp-udp)

Comment: Ok, it seems that it can be done with this type of tech.