# How do I write a code that starts playing animation, and stops playing it in 30 sec?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

This is a possible duplicate of my previous question, but the answers didn't help, so question remains the same. 
How do I write a code that starts playing animation, and stops playing it in 30 sec? I'm working in blender 2.79 and 2.80. 
Please give me an example of working code, that's really important for me now.

Comment: If you are referring to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146163/python-timer-is-not-working-for-me-in-blender it wasn't working for you on a version of blender that doesn't have `bpy.app.timers`    I can see no reason why passing screen to the timer and overriding context wouldn't work, as used (_similarly for a different op needing different context members_) in link  I posted in comments.  Did you attempt to get app timers working, or simply jump to this new question? The site _works_ much better if you make an attempt, rather than 
"_post me working code, and I'll tell you_"...

Comment: ... _if it works_.   On checking I realize I mistakenly pasted a circular link to  question , and have adjusted and answered, and posted correct link in answer. Please point out things like  wrong link to sort this out much earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Modal timer template**

Blender comes with a modal timer in its templates.  *`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Modal Timer`* Here is the timer for 2.8 converted to start playing when operator pressed, and stop after 30 seconds.

This part

```
self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1, window=context.window)
```

creates a `'TIMER'` event every second (the 1 designates 1 second, the original has 0.1 or a tenth of a second)

When 30 of these are counted (30 seconds) the animation is stopped.

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None
    count = 0

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'} or self.count > 30:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            self.count += 1


        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        # start animating
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1, window=context.window)
        self.count = 0
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)


        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

Comment: I realized it was my mistake, Ive been putting this code to python console, which doesnt work. And when I put it to text editor it perfectly works. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer [On Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/t/python-to-cancel-stop-animation/542796/3)

```
import bpy
def stop_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == 30:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

# add one of these functions to frame_change_pre handler:
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)
#start animation
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it when I get to work, and tell you if it works

Comment: Didn't work for me(

Comment: opps formatting issue, works out of the box now.

Comment: Works for me too! Thanks a lot man