# Stop running python script when animation plays, continue script after animation stops

Tags: python, animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I have writen a large Python script in Blender that does automatic sewing. First I will import a 3D-body, then import a T-shirt that is meant to be sewed. Then I place the body between the front & back of the T-shirt, assign cloth and collision modifiers.

Until this step all is good, then I play the animation using the code below, and intended to wait for the animation to stop at frame 30 then only continue execute the function `after_sew()`.

```
def sew(body_name, garment_name):
    body_obj = bpy.data.objects[body_name]
    garment_obj = bpy.data.objects[garment_name]
    s = bpy.context.scene
    s.frame_start = 1
    s.frame_end = 40
    s.frame_current = 1
    def stop_playback(scene):
        if scene.frame_current == 30:
            bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
            end = time()
            print(f"Sewing completed in {round(end-start,2)} seconds.")
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(stop_playback)
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

def after_sew():
    print("Sewing done")
    # Some other code

# Sewing
print("Now sewing... Please wait a few seconds.")
start = time()
sew(body_name, garment_name)
after_sew()
```

However, it is not going as expected. The script will call the `sew()` function, then execute `after_sew()` at the same time as animation is going. So I'm not able to get my desired output (at frame 30) in the `after_sew()` function.

I have searched for [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146330/how-do-i-write-a-code-that-starts-playing-animation-and-stops-playing-it-in-30), but this is about stopping animation after a certain time. For my case, I won't know how much time will be needed for animation depends on user device. Besides this I haven't found any relevant issue on BlenderSE. Maybe this is a really easy configuration but I just didn't manage to get it.

I also searched for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700629/python-wait-for-animation-to-be-completed), no answer is provided except the author himself, but I don't really know how to use bake option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like that you just need to invoke `after_sew()` in `stop_playback`:

```
def sew(body_name, garment_name):
    ....
    def stop_playback(scene):
        if scene.frame_current == 30:
            bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
            end = time()
            print(f"Sewing completed in {round(end-start,2)} seconds.")
            after_sew() <---------------
    ....

def after_sew():
    ....

# Sewing
print("Now sewing... Please wait a few seconds.")
start = time()
sew(body_name, garment_name)
```

`after_sew()` goes after `sew()` as you want. But that you do not want is that `stop_playback()` invokes later on a frame change.

Comment: Hi @Crantisz thanks for your comment. What if I have more than one function after it? I would have after_sew() for beautify the shirt, and export() for export the model, for example. Is it possible to manipulate the handle so that the script won't continue before handle finish?

Comment: and I kind of want to put all function after sewing below the sew() function instead of putting it in the handler function. That would makes the function flow more systematically.

Comment: This is how it works. Blender launches `sew()`, then `after_sew()`, then after some time frame_change_post triggers, and `stop_playback()` invokes 30 times, until animation stops by your script.

Comment: So `after_sew()` goes *after*  `sew()` as you want. But that you do not want is that `stop_playback()` invokes later on a frame change.

Comment: I see, thanks for you help!