# How to pass arguments/parameters to an operator class (bpy.types.Operator)?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, properties, operator

I am trying send an input argument to the `class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator)` but failing to do so. I am trying to send a `count` parameter which is basically a timer to run my animation for a certain time. I am using the following code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None
    count = IntProperty(default=0)

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'} or self.count > 30:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            self.count += 1


        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        # start animating
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1, window=context.window)
        self.count = 0
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)


        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator(count = 0)
```

The above code is from this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146334/172208) and the only change is that I'm trying to set the value of `count` from an input argument. I have modified the code following this [solution](https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-operator-with-arguments/550526/2) but I keep getting the following error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\user\blender_files\roughworks\test_actions.blend\Text", line 52, in <module>
  File "D:\user\softwares\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "count" unrecognized
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: change `count = IntProperty(default=0)` to `count : IntProperty(default=0)` should work.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello,  Ro.oT,  this looks like a duplicate, and, good, you have a fix, so safe to close. If you disagree, go ahead and edit for a re-open. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Robin, I agree. I couldn't find that question earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a syntax issue. Thanks to [X Y](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/109459/x-y) for pointing it out.

Simply changing `count = IntProperty(default=0)` to `count: IntProperty(default=0)` fixed the error.