# Python Script - Operator context is incorrect

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

The script I'm writing contains a bpy.app.timer which is supposed to detect if the user has manually exited Grease Pencil paint mode, then convert the grease pencil object to a curve. No matter what I try I just can't get past the 'context is incorrect' error.
Everything up to the convert operator works; for a selected pose bone a GP-Emtpy is added and you enter Paint Mode, if you draw something and then switch to Object Mode the timer finds it and goes on to execute the script below it - until it hits the convert operator. I tried invoking the area but then I get 'missing window in context' as an error. How can I set a context?

```
bl_info = {
"name": "Swoosh Animation",
"author": "Anton Lux",
"version": (1, 0),
"blender": (2, 83, 3),
"location": "View3D > Pose",
"description": "Animates Bones using GP Strokes",
"warning": "",
"doc_url": "",
"category": "Object",
}




import time
import bpy
import os
from pathlib import Path
from bpy.types import Operator, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import IntProperty, BoolProperty, FloatVectorProperty
from bpy.types import (
    AddonPreferences,
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)

class Object_OT_applyAnim(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "pose.apply_anim"
    bl_label = "Apply GP Animation"
    bl_description = "Apply the Animation to selected Bone"
    bl_space_type = "View_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        #defining timer to call later
        def every_2_seconds():
            if bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT':
                bpy.app.timers.unregister(every_2_seconds)
                #testing if timer found the new mode
                print("Cookies")
               
                
                
                #Converting GP to Curve
                bpy.ops.gpencil.convert('INVOKE_AREA', type='PATH', use_link_strokes=True, frame_range=500, use_realtime=True, use_timing_data=True)
                #Below here doesn't work either cause the context is noneType
                #Storing constraint target
                curve = bpy.context.selected_objects[1]

                #Setting up follow path constraint
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = Armature
                bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
                Bone.bone.select = True
                bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(relative_zero), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL')

                Bone.constraints["Follow Path"].target = curve


                #Baking constraint into keyframes
                bpy.ops.nla.bake(frame_start=1, frame_end=70, visual_keying=True, clear_constraints=True, bake_types={'POSE'})
                #Decimating keyframes
                bpy.ops.action.clean(threshold=0.001, channels=False)
            return 2.0       

         #Step 1 creating grease pencil stroke

        Bone = bpy.context.active_pose_bone
        boneName = bpy.context.active_pose_bone.name
        Armature = bpy.context.active_object
        Bone_tail = bpy.context.active_pose_bone.tail
        relative_zero =  (Armature.location + Bone_tail) * (-1)
        window = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0]
        
        #Leaving Pose Mode
        bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
        #Adding GP Empty
        bpy.ops.object.gpencil_add(align='WORLD', location= Bone.location, type='EMPTY')
        bpy.context.object.name = boneName        
        
        #Entering Paint Mode
        bpy.ops.gpencil.paintmode_toggle()
        
        #Step 2 activating the timer defined above
        bpy.app.timers.register(every_2_seconds)
        
        
        
            
     
       


        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def menu_func2 (self,context):
    self.layout.operator(Object_OT_applyAnim.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Object_OT_applyAnim)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_pose.append(menu_func2)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Object_OT_applyAnim)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_pose.remove(menu_func2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Consider  a modal timer operator.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135970/context-is-incorrect-when-calling-from-a-timer    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146163/python-timer-is-not-working-for-me-in-blender  When context is passed as an argument _ie_ `def foo(self, context)` use it rather than `bpy.context` in method code

Comment: Thx a lot. That did the trick. You're a legend.