# Context issues while importing Alembic files in a plugin

Tags: python, error, operator, alembic

I keep getting the context is incorrect error and the error is: Operator bpy.ops.wm.alembic_import.poll() failed.

I have tried all the solutions shared in this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) and in the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html) and the issue still persist.

I am running this command:

```
bpy.ops.wm.alembic_import(filepath=meshPath, as_background_job=False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This caused by calling operator form console or text editor.
Here is some sumular cases https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135995/23459, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/23459.
The simplest solution is to create your own operator (blender has templates), register it and call from search (F3) menu.

Comment: Even if you don't get an answer, please don't ask the same question multiple times.