# Modal Operators Timing/Profiling

Tags: python, scripting

Trying to get a feeling for the timing of Modal Operators I did some experiments and need some advice on how to interpret them

I experimented with this script

```
import bpy
import time


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            print((time.time_ns() - self.old_time)/1.0e9)
            while self.i < 10:
                self.i += 1
            self.i = 0
            self.old_time = time.time_ns()
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.01, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        self.old_time = time.time_ns()
        self.i = 0

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

# test call
bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

on my machine the minimum timing for the timer is 10ms

I then timed the while loop in the execute method of the operator

8s    for counting to 1 000 000

0.8   for               100 000

0.1   for                10 000

0.01  for                 1 000

0.002 for                   100

0.001 for                    10

OK, consistent

then I put the while loop in the modal method (as in the script above)

as long as the execution time of the while loop is less than the frequency of the timer everything is fine.

But as soon as the execution time is larger than the frequency the print statement starts to print additional 0.0!

WHY?

What is the scheduler doing?

THX
Martin

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194818/15543  The elapsed time can be gleaned from the timer. The timer event fires every 0.01 seconds ( for `wm.event_timer_add(0.01,...`  With the while loop where it is, it will pretty much be   instant to iterate / decrement over 10,

Comment: @batFINGER of course the iteration to 10 will be almost instantly but as the time for the while loop increases ( increasing the count to let's say 100 000 ) the additional print statements get executed